# Manage Block Java

Tags: java

I have this  block:

```
ConnectToServer.login(user, pw, new CallbackVoid() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        onSuccessLogin(pw, user);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable cause) {

    }
});
```

My question is this:

call "login" method I perform login on my server and if is successful I go to onSuccess method  , else I go to onFailure.
My problem is that I can go in "onFailure" method for 2 reasons:

1) username or password are incorrect

2) There was a problem connecting to the server

I would like to see a different error message. 
for example, if the username is wrong I would like to see "username incorrect" while if you have not established a connection to the server I see "try again later".

But to do this I need to know the precise reason of error how do I?

Thank for your time

Comment: Why don't you use the fields of `cause`? Without knowing what exactly will call your callback, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onFailure()` method has a `Throwable cause` parameter. This is the actual exception (or error) that occurred.

Usually it is enough to check the actual class of `cause` to know what the issue was. For example if `cause` is an instance of `java.io.IOException` then it's probably some kind of IO error and not a wrong username/password.

My suggestion would be to check what class of exception is returned when you input a wrong username or a wrong password (try both, in case they return different values), then code something like this :

```
if(cause instanceof TheBadUsernameOrPasswordException){
  //TODO manage your wrong username or password here
}else{
  //TODO manage any other type of error here
}
```

In any case, you should log the exact exception so that administrators can debug it.